# asp.net placing multiple MSChart controls on the same page

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I tried to place 4 mschart controls on the same page but it is giving me major grief. Each chart appears properly when I place one per page, but as soon as I place multiple the first two are displaying incorrect data and the last two do no display anything at all.

I made sure that I am not using the same session variable eventhough that seems to be the most like culprit.

Comment: I have a similar problem, 5 charts, they all show the data of the latest chart...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by placing each chart in its own IFrame.